# Querying nested set model upside down

Tags: mysql, sql, nested-sets

I've got a webshop with a tree of categories stored as a nested set tree (lft, rgt and lvl attributes for each category).

What I want to do is show all categories which contains a certain type of product as a full tree. I can easily get Ids of all categories in question either as a separate SQL or with a join. The problem is; I get only the deep child category, and what I really need is the full path of that category.

Example (`SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY lft`):

- Music

  - LP
  - CD
- Movies

  - VHS
  - DVD
- Books

  - Paperback
  - Hardcover

Let's say I want to show categories with new material and that happens only to be DVD and LP:

(`SELECT * FROM categories WHERE new > 0 (OR IS PARENT OF SUCH) ORDER BY lft`):

- Music

  - LP
- Movies

  - DVD

Hope someone is able to help, thanks in advance!

(Just out of curiosity: is it possible to accumulate a number upwards? Eg. the "new" counter? So that music.new would always be bigger or equal to LP.new)

Comment: What database are you using?  The solution is highly database dependent.  Also, is there a maximum depth?

Comment: MySQL and no maximum theoretical depth